# DNS Packets being dropped

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I have two instances of Microsoft server 2016 Standard edition running on a Dell PowerEdge T330 server in Hyper-V. One of the instances is my domain controller, and runs DHCP and DNS. There are two Brodcom network adapters on the host machine, one is dedicated to the host, and one is dedicated to a Hyper-V virtual switch.

I recently migrated my domain controller to one of the Hyper-V instances. When I changed the DNS server from DHCP I started seeing DNS issues. I don't seem to have any DNS issues on any of my windows workstations joined to the domain. I'm having issues with several mobile devices. I ran a packet capture on the host machine and I don't see any DNS packets from the device I'm testing with. If I reset the network connection on the device, I will see the packets going through DNS queries will resolve, but then I will see no packets going through and no DNS queries will resolve. Even though I don't see any packets going through from the DNS server, I'm still able to ping the DNS server from the device, and it's not saying I'm dropping any packets.

This is the packet I see before I stop receiving packets.

```
IGMPv2  60  Leave Group
```

Comment: `When I changed the DNS server from DHCP I started seeing DNS issues.` Can you clarify that statement? What exactly did you do?

Comment: In the scope options I changed the IP address for the DNS server from my old domain controller to my new domain controller.